# TypeError: inject.endpoints is not a function

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I was reading [RTK Query Quick Start tutorial](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/rtk-query) and was trying it in javascript while running it shown me this error.

[image]

Example at the corresponding site has shown both Typescript and Javascript code, but sandbox example is in typescript.

src/app/services/pokemon.js

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
export const pokemonApi = createApi({
    reducerPath:'pokemonApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2'
    }),
    enedpoints: (builder)=>({
        getPokemonByName: builder.query({
            query:(name)=>`pokemon/${name}`,
        }),
    }),
});

export const { useGetPokemonByNameQuery } = pokemonApi
```

src/app.jsx

```js
import { useGetPokemonByNameQuery } from './services/pokemon';

export default function App(){
const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetPokemonByNameQuery('bulbasaur');
  
  return (
<div className="App">
  {error ? (
    <>Oh no, there was an error</>
  ) : isLoading ? (
    <>Loading...</>
  ) : data ? (
    <>
      <h3>{data.species.name}</h3>
      <img src={data.sprites.front_shiny} alt={data.species.name} />
    </>
  ) : null}
</div>
  );
}
```

src/app/store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query";
import counterReducer from "../features/counter/counterSlice";
import { pokemonApi } from "../services/pokemon";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer:{
        counter: counterReducer,
        [pokemonApi.reducerPath]: pokemonApi.reducer,
    },

    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware)=>
        getDefaultMiddleware().concat(pokemonApi.middleware),
});

// optional, but required for refetchOnFocus/refetchOnReconnect behaviors
// see `setupListeners` docs - takes an optional callback as the 2nd arg for customization
setupListeners(store.dispatch)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo there. `enedpoints` instead of `endpoints`.

Answer (score 4):

this Error sometimes comes up if we do not specify endpoint at createApi "inject.endpoints is not a function".

```js
export const ApiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api',
    baseQuery: axiosBaseQuery,
    endpoints: () => ({}) // <= This line is Mandatory even if empty 
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem;

I had a typo on `endpoints`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).